# Control speed on track path with locked track

Tags: bezier-curves, camera, path

I have this scene with a camera moving on a bezier curve (Track path), maintaining a lock on an object (locked track), and it works pretty well!

[image]

Now the problem is, the camera starts and stopd abruptly, always mainting the same speed, I want to change this by adding some keyframe and doing some curves on the speed values.

[image]

No luck at all! Is there a way I can modify it's speed and acceleration values?

I have tried instead of parenting the track path, creating a constraint like this:

[image]

But everything seems to break for some reason. And even if it wouldn't break, I am not sure if this way I would be able to modify it's speed/acceleration values!

Trully appreciate some help here!

Comment: as in the warning: it is locked, sampled, do you have f-modifiers? if unsure, can you share your file example on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this was quite simple, to create keyframes in the track path parent, as the error stated, I had to remove the F modifier.

[image]

Creating the constraint kept breaking everything for me, no idea how to fix that, but I got this working now... Happy times!